# Django Rest Framework does not deserialize data passed as raw JSON

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the following view:

```
class Authenticate(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = AuthSerializer

    def create(self, request):
        serializer = AuthSerializer(request.POST)
        # Do work here
```

This works well if the data is passed as a form, however, if the data is passed as a raw JSON the serializer is instantiated with all it's fields set to None. The documentation does mention that there should be anything specific to processing a raw JSON argument.

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I have the following work around in order to make the Browsable API work as expected when passing a raw JSON but I believe there must be a better way.

```
def parse_data(request):
    # If this key exists, it means that a raw JSON was passed via the Browsable API
    if '_content' in request.POST:
        stream = StringIO(request.POST['_content'])
        return JSONParser().parse(stream)
    return request.POST


class Authenticate(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = AuthSerializer

    def create(self, request):
        serializer = AuthSerializer(parse_data(request))
        # Do work here
```

Comment: what's the error you got? Or did you actually get any error?

Comment: The serializer is initialised with Nones. The problem is that the Browsable API sends the JSON inside a '_content' key. I have created a function to identify when this is the case and parse the json to a dict but I believe there must be a better way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're accessing the request data the wrong way - `request.POST` only handles parsing form multipart data.

Use REST framework's `request.data` instead.  That'll handle either form data, or json data, or whatever other parsers you have configured.

Comment: Nothing like an answer from the creator of the framework himself :)

Comment: I have the same problem with request.data, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I guess that's the way it is when you are using Browsable API then.

I think you shouldn't use Browsable API to test JSON request, use `curl` instead:

```
curl -v -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"foo": 1, "bar": 1}' http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/something/
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The other developers expect to use the Browsable API to validate their JSON and as the Browsable API has a tab to post raw JSON I assume there is something to make the serializer work with that. I have posted an issue on the project's Github page. A simple check on the Serializer's __init__ should do the trick and make it work out of the box.

Comment: nice, let me know of the result then ;)